# Excel Export is not working in Kendo ui for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to export kendo grid using the following code:

```
<body>

<button id="export">Export to Excel</button>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
      { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ],
});
$("#export").click(function(e) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.saveAsExcel();
});
</script>
</body>
```

But this method is not working. I'm using kendo 2017 version. I have also include the jszip script, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: can you be more specific on which version of kendo scripts are using? eg: 2017.x.xxx

Comment: @sisonkk I'm using 2017.1.118

Comment: hope you are using same version of _jquery.min.js_ and _kendo.all.min.js_

Comment: @sisonkk Yes. I'm using the same versions

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

I think It's because of your `jszip` version for `Kendo UI 2017`.

Check your `jszip` version.

> As of the Kendo UI R3 2017 release, the Excel Export feature supports JSZip 2.* and 3.* versions. Kendo UI releases prior to R2 2017 SP1 provided Excel export of JSZip 2.* versions only.

Check the reference here : [Excel Export Requirements](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/excel/introduction)